# Adobe AIR captures stage and convert to RTMP stream

Tags: apache-flex, air, rtmp, screen-capture, flash-media-server

I'm creating an AIR app that will run on our server. I essentially want the app to do a screen capture of sorts of the app's stage and convert it to an RTMP stream for publishing to FMS OR write a video file right to the disk.

RTMP Stream would prob be the most ideal.

I know you can get the bitmap data pretty easily, but I don't know how to take the bitmap data as it's changing and convert to a stream.

Anyone have a clue ?

Thanks in advance.